# Prune Down Autocomplete Terms

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I have a very large list of terms for use in an autocomplete box. I've been mulling over a few different scenarios for how to prune them down, but I haven't come up with anything great yet.

Basically, the structure is very similar to a record label -

- An artist has albums An album has songs
- Individual songs could be popular, albums are mostly sums of their underlying song popularity
- Albums also have highly variable number of songs in them - so if an album has hundreds of song, it's very likely that someone would want to search for it, and much less likely
  if it has less songs
- As the autocomplete becomes more specific (more letters), I'd like less likely terms to be shown

I'm thinking something like this:

```
Apple   10
Banana  10
Crab    20
Diner   30
Dish    20
Daily   10
Diver   20
Dice    10
```

If this is the list of albums, and the "score" i assign them, I simply pop choose the list based on the length of the list I'm showing (3 for example) and then by score - I hit "D" above, and "Diner", "Dish" and "Diver" show up, and then "i" and it becomes "Diner", "Dish" and "Diver".

Is there a particular algorithm that does this? Or an AJAX autocompleter built for this? I'm currently using Prototype/Scriptaculous but I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an easy algorithm to implement, since you are trying to index a data structure in two ways - lexicographically and by popularity.

One way to do it might be to build a [compressed trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Compressing_tries) of the songs, where at each node you store a pre-built list of the N most popular songs beginning with that prefix. This would take a lot of storage (O(NUM_SONGS * N)), but would allow fast lookup (O(PREFIX)).

Comment: This looks great and is probably the best I can expect. Any implementations of this?

Answer (score 4):

I just posted a [server-side autocomplete implementation](http://code.google.com/p/autocomplete-server/) on Google Code.  The project includes a java library that can be integrated into existing applications and a standalone HTTP AJAX autocomplete server. Kick the tires!

Comment: This _is_ really cool - and solves a lot of my problems. Any chance that there's a Ruby version available?

Comment: You should be able to download the jar file, run it as a standalone server, and connect to it from ruby.  See the python example code on the homepage as a starting point for writing a simple ruby client.

In the interest of full disclosure, I haven't extensively tested the server wrapper code.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the [closure autocomplete](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/docs/class_goog_ui_AutoComplete.html) a try.